# Align elements inside a newcommand

Tags: spacing, macros, horizontal-alignment, acronyms, recursion

I made this newcommand `\boldAcr`:

```
\makeatletter % we need to use kernel commands
\newcommand{\boldAcr[1]}{\MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{#1}}\@boldAcrOne}
\newcommand\@boldAcrOne{\@ifnextchar\stopBold{\@boldSend}{\@boldAcrTwo}}
\newcommand\@boldAcrTwo[1]{\@boldAcrThree{#1}\@boldAcrOne%restart the recursion
}
\newcommand\@boldAcrThree[1]{ \fb{#1}} %Space
\newcommand\@boldSend[1]{% The argument is \stopBold    
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\fb}[1]{\dofb#1}
\newcommand{\dofb}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{#1}}}
```

and I call it this way:

```
\boldAcr[owasp] {open} {web} {application} {security} {project} \stopBold \\
\boldAcr[xss] {cross} {site} {scripting} \stopBold \\
```

That is the result.
[image: Result]

Is there a way to add spacing after the first word, to make all the others start from a specific point?
I mean like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd use a simpler input syntax, perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\boldAcr#1 {\makebox[2cm][l]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}} \boldAcrB}
\def\boldAcrB#1 {\ifx\\#1\par\else\boldAcrC#1 \expandafter\boldAcrB\fi}
\def\boldAcrC#1{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\boldAcr owasp open web application security project \\
\boldAcr xss cross site scripting \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could of course add `\makebox[2cm][l]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase` to your version to force the first word to be 2cm wide, you don't have to change the input syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can do better with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\boldAcrwidth}
\setlength{\boldAcrwidth}{2cm}

\NewDocumentCommand{\boldAcr}{m >{\SplitList{ }}m}{%
  \makebox[\boldAcrwidth][l]{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \ProcessList{#2}{\boldAcrFirst}%
  \unskip
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\boldAcrFirst}{m}{%
  \boldAcrFirstAux#1 % we want a space
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\boldAcrFirstAux}{m}{%
  \textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\boldAcr{owasp}{open web application security project} \\
\boldAcr{xss}{cross site scripting} \\

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

The second argument is split at spaces; each item is passed to the macro `\boldAcrFirst` that simply calls `\boldAcrFirstAux` which only uses the first letter, making it boldface and uppercase, typesetting the rest normally and adding a trailing space. The last space is removed by `\unskip`.

[image]